# Simplest JSON Schema documentation generator

Tags: documentation, jsonschema

I've spent a few off-clock hours looking for a stupid easy way to take my JSON Schema file as input and generate some kind of human-friendly output. I don't even care what format that output is at this point, as long as it is complete-ish. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the following util from cloudflare: https://github.com/cloudflare/doca

Comment: What is the util about? How to go about using it? Link-only answers should be avoided.

Comment: I actually found that util before and kept googling, because I coultnlt get it to work. It downloaded like 10MB of libraries from `npm`, just for start. Doesn't sound as simple. And it isn't compatible with Windows, it uses linux commands in makes steps.

Comment: Same thing here, I gave it a try and struggle to make it work for an hour :/ too bad